# Python MySQL returns wrong rows for a query but Phpmyadmn shows right rows

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to get the first and last record from a month. In phpmyadmin I get the correct result. In python I don't. In fact python returns the same row for both of these queries. First number is the table primary key for the rows.

```
SELECT * FROM mcs WHERE time_stamp < DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( LAST_DAY( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL 25 HOUR ) , INTERVAL -2 MONTH) AND wot_id = 1010965979 LIMIT 1
((838831, '1010965979', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 22, 0), Decimal('444.88'), Decimal('0.00')),)
SELECT * FROM mcs WHERE time_stamp < DATE_ADD( DATE_ADD( LAST_DAY( NOW( ) ) , INTERVAL 24 HOUR ) , INTERVAL -1 MONTH)AND wot_id = 1010965979 LIMIT 1
((838831, '1010965979', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 22, 0), Decimal('444.88'), Decimal('0.00')),)
```

phpmyadmin shows this row for the first query,

839037 1010965979 2015-04-01 00:00:00 437.36 0.00

and this for the second:

953868 1010965979 2015-04-30 23:00:00 479.67 0.00

using MySQLdb and python 3

What is wrong? is this a bug in MySQLdb? I would not think so as it just passes a SQL string to mysql

EDIT:

I get the same problem using unix time.  Why does copy and past of same SQL give different results on the same database?

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=4, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=2, tm_min=18, tm_sec=51, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=91, tm_isdst=-1)
1427846400
SELECT * FROM mcs WHERE time_stamp < FROM_UNIXTIME(1427846400) AND wot_id = 1010965979 LIMIT 1
((838831, '1010965979', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 22, 0), Decimal('444.88'), Decimal('0.00')),)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=2, tm_min=18, tm_sec=51, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=121, tm_isdst=-1)
1430438400
SELECT * FROM mcs WHERE time_stamp < FROM_UNIXTIME(1430438400) AND wot_id = 1010965979 LIMIT 1
((838831, '1010965979', datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 6, 22, 0), Decimal('444.88'), Decimal('0.00')),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it,  PhpMyadmin must be silently placing an 'order by' in the SQL.

changing it to

SELECT * FROM mcs WHERE time_stamp < FROM_UNIXTIME(1427846400) AND wot_id = 1010965979 ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 1

works as expected.